# Row-Level Security filters on Dataset not applying to the Report (Power BI service)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

**MY GOAL:** Have working Roles on Power BI service

I have a Power BI Report formatted like a table, where each row represents a project, and the columns are things like "Project Manager" and other project details. There is a dataset for this that I have not worked with that combines like 8 other data tables.

On Power BI service, I went to the report and clicked "View Dataset". Then from the dataset, I clicked "Open Data Model". From here I clicked "Manage Roles" and made a role called "No Access" for testing, and I set access to each table to "FALSE", so that this role cannot view anything in the table.

I then assigned myself to the role. To my surprise, when I went back to the Report and refreshed, everything looked the same. (I only created this "No Access" role after my initial role didn't work, and this proves the issue is that the role is not applying to the report somehow.)

If you need more clarification on what the issue is I can provide more details. It seems like the roles I put on the dataset are not applying to the report.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to solicit paid work. I've edited your post.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like the roles I put on the dataset are not applying to the report.

Row-level security is not applied to users with Workspace roles greater than Viewer.

> Row-level security (RLS) with Power BI can be used to restrict data
> access for given users. Filters restrict data access at the row level,
> and you can define filters within roles. In the Power BI service,
> users with access to a workspace have access to datasets in that
> workspace. **RLS only restricts data access for users with Viewer
> permissions. It doesn't apply to Admins, Members, or Contributors.**

[Row-level security (RLS) with Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls)